# Not able to delete 'matchId' column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this

[image]

I tried to delete **matchId** but no matter what I use to delete it, for preprocessing, its outputting this error:

```
KeyError: "['matchId'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: because that is an index, you can do `df.reset_index(drop=True)` if you dont want to see it and assign it back `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thank you so much,I didn't realize that its a index :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you attempted to do (which you should have mentioned in the question) is probably failing because you assume that the `matchID` column is a normal column. It is actually a special, **index** column and so cannot be accessed in the same way other columns can be accessed.

As suggested by anky_91, because of that, you should do

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

if you want to completely remove the indexes in your table. This will replace them with the default indexes. To just make them into another column, you can just remove the `drop=True` from the above statement.

Your table will always have indexes, however, so you cannot completely get rid of them.

You can, however, output it with

```
df.values
```

and this will ignore the indexes and show just the values as arrays.